# Should I use DELETE method if resource is not actually deleted, but just tagged as deleted with timestamp?

Tags: rest

I have no code to show, since I think the subject speaks for itself. What should be the proper HTTP verb to use here? DELETE or PATCH?

Basically, data will just be tagged as isDel=true, delAt=*timestamp*.

Update (02/26/2023):

Fetching the data will result to 404 Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC-2616 has [this to say](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) regarding DELETE:

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI. This method MAY be overridden by human intervention (or other means) on the origin server. The client cannot be guaranteed that the operation has been carried out, even if the status code returned from the origin server indicates that the action has been completed successfully. However, the server SHOULD NOT indicate success unless, at the time the response is given, it intends to delete the resource or **move it to an inaccessible location**.

If the value of `isDel` indicates that the record cannot be accessed by a subsequent GET, then IMO that counts as moving the resource to an inaccessible location, and so DELETE is appropriate.

Note that such a record could be efficiently *restored* by a future PUT simply by toggling the value of `isDel`, rather than having to recreate the resource:

```
PUT /foo/bar   # Create the resource
GET /foo/bar   # Retrieve it
DELETE /foo/bar  # "Delete" it
GET /foo/bar   # 404 not found
PUT /foo/bar   # Make it available again
GET /foo/bar   # Retrieve it
```

Comment: This is a good insight. And to restore the data via PUT although I did not ask for it, but adds value to the topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

"It depends".

If you are editing a representation, for instance adding `isDel` and `delAt` properties to a document and sending those changes to the server, then you should be using one of the methods intended for mutating representations (PATCH or PUT or POST).

If you are [removing the association](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) between a resource and its representations, then DELETE is fine.  If it happens that the server modifies the representations as a side effect of the DELETE... well, that's just an implementation detail that is hidden behind the HTTP facade.

---

If you are imagining sending a payload with the request, then DELETE is right out, because the payload of a DELETE request has no defined semantics -- there are no guarantees that general purpose components will forward the payload all the way through to the origin server.

Also note:

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect.

Remember that DELETE, just like the other HTTP methods, is an expression of semantics in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s) domain, not *your* problem domain.

---

> As much as I'd like it to be PATCH
> indempotency needs to be considered

Then you should think about implementing PUT, also.

PUT and PATCH are both rooted in "remote authoring"; the client makes changes to a local representation of a resource, and then asks the server to make those same changes to its local copy.

The difference between the two: with PUT, we send the entire representation of the resource; with PATCH, we send a patch document that describes only the changes.

If you implement both of these methods on your server, then the client can choose the appropriate method for its conditions.  For example, if the size of the representation is small relative to the HTTP headers, the client might  always choose to use PUT, because the HTTP application can take advantage of the method constraints if the message transport is unreliable.

On the other hand, when the representation is very big, and the changes are small, then sending a patch may make more sense.

---

> They are just server-side state not retrievable by GET or any existing API that we have.

If the semantics of DELETE are not appropriate, and you aren't looking at information that belongs in the representation, then [it is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of "this action isn’t worth standardizing." -- Fielding, 2008

Comment: It's adding 'isDel' & 'delAt' if not existing, or update when they already exist, so it's PATCH. Yeah, it actually depends and would boil down to concurrence I guess, since the trivial answer is that it depends. As much as I'd like it to be PATCH, I'm resolved with the idea that you can only delete (regardless if it's just tagging) a resource once unless it's restored in a scenario where multiple same request is sent to the server. Meaning, indempotency needs to be considered in choosing the right method. Hence, I think what weighs if not the answer to the question per se is DELETE. IMO.

Comment: My first choice though was PATCH. Then context of what consumer should know also influences the choice. They don't and should not know that deletion is just by means of updating a tag.

Comment: PUT gives you idempotent semantics while staying within the remote authoring idiom; see extended answer.

Comment: @duduwe It's only a patch if the values of `isDel` and `delAt` are retrievalble via GET. If they are just server-side state used to ensure that `DELETE resource; GET resource` results in a 404, the `DELETE` is correct.

Comment: @chepner I think that can be a consideration as well. They are just server-side state not retrievable by GET or any existing API that we have.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, will using PUT not require sending other fields as well? Bec it needs to rebuild the data/collection. If I only need to add/update isDel & delAt in an existing collection, shouldn't it be PATCH/POST?

Comment: If you are using PUT, then the client should be sending a copy of the entire representation, not just the edits you made.  It's a tradeoff: we send "redundant" information so that we can safely leverage the capabilities of the general purpose components.  If you are sending a patch-document instead of the representation, then you should use PATCH (but that's not constrained to be idempotent, so the HTTP application can't do as much smart stuff).

Comment: It's a difference between *you* updating the attributes because they are part of the record and the *server* updating them because they are metadata used to implement HTTP semantics.